# converting timestamp to date gives wrong date in php

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I'm having trouble getting the correct date from my timestamp while echoing out from files being pulled from an folder on an ftp.

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator("blahblahblah/news");
$files = array();
foreach($it as $file) {
if (!$it->isDot()) {
    $files[] = array($file->getMTime(), $file->getFilename());
}}

rsort($files);
 foreach ($files as $f) {
     $mil = $f[0];
     $seconds = $mil / 1000;
     $seconds = round($seconds);
     $theDate = date("d/m/Y", $seconds);
echo "<img src=\"images/content/social-icons/article.png\" width=\"18\" height=\"19\" alt=\"article\">" . $theDate . "-  <a  style=\"background-color:transparent;\" href=\"news/$f[1]\">" . $f[1] . "</a>";
echo "<br>";

 }
```

I'm sorting the files by timestamp, then trying to echo them out with the filename and a link to the file.
The problem is that the date() comes out to january 16 1970... I've put the timestamps into an online converter and they are accurate, so I am confused.
I've also rounded the timestamps but that does not help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getMTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getmtime.php) returns a Unix Timestamp.

Unix Timestamps are typically the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (NOT the number of milliseconds).  [See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getmtime.php).

So this: `$seconds = $mil / 1000;` is your source of error.

Simply set `$seconds = $f[0]` and you should be good to go.

Corrected code:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator("blahblahblah/news");
$files = array();
foreach($it as $file) {
if (!$it->isDot()) {
    $files[] = array($file->getMTime(), $file->getFilename());
}}

rsort($files);
 foreach ($files as $f) {
     $seconds = $f[0];
     $seconds = round($seconds);
     $theDate = date("d/m/Y", $seconds);
echo "<img src=\"images/content/social-icons/article.png\" width=\"18\" height=\"19\" alt=\"article\">" . $theDate . "-  <a  style=\"background-color:transparent;\" href=\"news/$f[1]\">" . $f[1] . "</a>";
echo "<br>";

 }
```